# Application.EnableEvents defaults to False

Tags: vba, excel

This is happening to users with Excel 2007/2010 who are using Worksheet_Change and Worksheet_SelectionChange events that I've designed in 2013.

What seems to be happening is that when they first open the workbook, their worksheet events do not fire. I've made sure they have their options defaulted to enable macros. If I open the immediate window and run `Application.EnableEvents = True` then their events start firing just fine. Users with Excel 2013 don't seem to have this issue, even when opening the exact same copy of the workbook from a shared network drive.

I seem to have been able to fix this by putting `Application.EnableEvents = True` under the Workbook_Open event, but I wonder about this as a viable long-term solution. I'd would really rather figure out why this be happening in the first place to address it directly.

Comment: This is just a stab in the dark,  In one of your Events you are using `On Error Resume Next` or `Goto Something`.  And the code is not backwards compatible with 2007/2010.  So when the error happens it is ignored and the `Application.EnableEvents = True` in that code is being skipped.  Remove all error handlers in the code and open the book in the older versions and see what error happens.

Comment: Since the Workbook_Open event is firing, it seems events are enabled at the start. Maybe some incompatibility is causing it to revert to False when certain events cause issues

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue today on some Word VBA. And it was located in a hidden project. It turned out that the On Error event handlers we incorrectly coded by someone else. I used the AutoExec and AutoOpen macros and inserted a Stop to go into debugging mode and see what happens.

These events should fire unless you had set the EnableEvents to False in your code to begin with.